# Windows Server 2022 openssh sftp change default directory

Tags: windows, ssh, openssh, sftp, windows-server-2022

Windows Server 2022

Installed optional feature OpenSSH Server

With FileZilla I connect to server as MyUser which opens to

```
/C:/Users/MyUser/
```

which is the default directory.

But what I want is for the sftp home folder to map to `C:/sftp/`

According to OpenSSH instructions I need to modify sshd_config

I only find this file

```
C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\sshd_config_default
```

( although this file is not marked read-only, apparently is can't be edited or overwritten )

so I created a copy

```
C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\sshd_config
```

and modified the line :

```
Subsystem sftp sftp-server.exe -d "C:\sftp"
```

Next I restarted the OpenSSH Server Windows Service.

However, FileZilla still connects to `/C:/Users/MyUser/`

Answer (score 0):

Try checking in `C:\ProgramData\ssh\` instead:

> Open SSH Server (sshd) reads configuration data from `%programdata%\ssh\sshd_config` by default.
>
> If the file is absent, sshd generates one with the default configuration (sshd_config_default) when the service is started.

See more details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_server_configuration#openssh-configuration-files